# simultaniusly append two lists with one function output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to append two list with one output:

```
def func(x) : return "foo" + str(x), "bar"+ str(x)
   

foo_list = []
bar_list = []

for i in range(3):
    foo, bar = func(i)
    foo_list.append(foo)
    bar_list.append(bar)
```

is it possible to do this without temporary vaiables?

Comment: write a function to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly possible, but it isn't simpler to understand. So don't do it, but this would be the way:

```
for i in range(3):
    any(map(list.append, (foo_list, bar_list), func(i)))
```

Comment: @mhwh It is a way to exhaust the iterator returned by map(), otherwise the mapped function is not applied. You could also use `list(map(...))` (but it costs some memory) or `for _ in map(...): pass` (which would be slower). We can use any() because we know that list.append returns `None` which is falsy, so any() will exhaust the iterator looking for a truey value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this but it will make the function call two times instead of one.

```
def func(x) : return "foo" + str(x), "bar"+ str(x)
   
foo_list = []
bar_list = []

for i in range(3):
    foo_list.append(func(i)[0])
    bar_list.append(func(i)[1])
```

Comment: this would execute func() twice and if func is expensive this makes the code very inefficient

Comment: Yes, that's what I had mentioned in the first line of my solution.

Comment: OK, then try this: